# Hiding specific tag<td> containing certain string(user id)

Tags: javascript, tags, hide

Site address: http://tcafe2a.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=free

I want to remove a few posts done by user-id "captinharu".

I did the following(in Tampermonkey script) and it removed most of the webpages instead of just post done by 'captainharu' and I have no idea. Please help.

```
function rmvtd2(name) {
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++)
    {
        var elementHtml = t[i].outerHTML;
        var n1 = elementHtml.indexOf(name);
        if(n1>1){
                t[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
rmvtd2("captinharu");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case, this solution works. But may not be valid for all the cases.

```
function rmvtd2(name) {
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++)
    {
        var elementHtml = t[i].outerHTML;
        var n1 = elementHtml.indexOf(name);
        if(n1 > -1 && n1 < 1000){
            t[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
rmvtd2("captinharu");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with `querySelectorAll()`?

```
let name ='captinharu';
    document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function (item){
        const regex = RegExp(name);
        if(regex.test(item.innerText)){
            item.setAttribute('hidden',true);
            // or ->  item.classList.add('hidden'); 
            // or ->  item.remove(); 
        };
    })
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't work for me.

Comment: To hide the entire row you can replace 'td' to 'tr', it works for me ! https://codepen.io/VivienGriffon/pen/GRjjaKw

Answer (score 0):

DOM hide some thing. You can use simply javascript to manage them like
to hide ...
`t[i].style.display = 'none';`

to show ...
`t[i].style.display = '';`

Comment: It still removes the whole page. I only want to remove the captinharu's post.

Comment: try this command 
```document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((e,i) => { e.innerText.includes(name) ? e.remove() : null } );```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((e,i) => { e.innerText.includes(name) ? e.remove() : null } ); still removes whole page for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the row by doing something like this:

```
function hideUserPost(username){
    $("#tbl_board .member").each(function( index ) {
      if($( this ).text() == username){
            $( this ).closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
}

hideUserPost('Captain Day');
```

Comment: I have // @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js in the script but it still says $ is undefined and it won't run this code, do I have to add anything else?

Comment: I ran this code in the console it works fine. I think you need to run this code after jquery initialization.